# Android - How to make AI which do auto validate?

Tags: android, automation

[image]

I want to make auto validation. If user already input name, choose character and choose game type user can click OK button. But, if user doesn't do that 2 things, user can't click OK button.

Here's my source code :

value in editText is processed in method SET NAME

value in game type spinner is processed in method SETGAMETYPES

```
public class UserConfig extends Activity {
Button userConfigBack;
Button userConfigOK;
EditText userNameTextbox;
Spinner gameTypes;
Spinner gameTimes;
private String gameType;
private String gameTime;
private String playerName;
private int IDChar = 0; 
private Handler handler;
Thread validation;
int isValidate = 0;
TextView nameLabel;
TextView gameTypeLabel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.user_config);
     userConfigBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.user_config_back);
     userConfigOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.user_config_ok);
     userNameTextbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name_textbox);
     gameTypes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.game_types);
     gameTimes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.game_times);
     //gameTypes.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     //gameTimes.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     userConfigOK.setEnabled(false);
     userConfigOK.setClickable(false);
     nameLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
     gameTypeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_config_label1);
     setName();
     chooseCharacter();
     setGameType();
     handler = new Handler();
     back();
    // autoValidation();
     OK();

}


public void setName() {
    playerName = userNameTextbox.getText().toString();

     userNameTextbox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                playerName = userNameTextbox.getText().toString();
                nameLabel.setText(playerName);
                 if(!userNameTextbox.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                     userConfigOK.setEnabled(true);
                     userConfigOK.setClickable(true);

                 }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {
                playerName = userNameTextbox.getText().toString();
                nameLabel.setText(playerName);
                if( e.length() >= 12 )
                {
                    //user tidak bisa mengetik nama lagi
                }

            } 

        });


}

public void chooseCharacter() {

}

public void setGameType() {
    gameTypes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            gameType = (String) gameTypes.getSelectedItem();
            gameTypeLabel.setText(gameType);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });

}

public void setGameTime() {
    gameTimes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            //An AdapterView is a view whose children are determined by an Adapter.
            gameTime = (String) gameTimes.getSelectedItem(); 

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

public void back() {
    userConfigBack.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(UserConfig.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public void OK() {

    userConfigOK.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(UserConfig.this, EnemyConfig1.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


}
}
```

Here's xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/user_config_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/user_config_back"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/user_config_back"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
        android:text="OK" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choose_character"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_name_textbox"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Choose Character"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/user_config_back"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/char_1"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
         android:text="Back" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/char_1"
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/user_name"
         android:layout_below="@+id/choose_character"
         android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
         android:src="@drawable/char_1"
         android:text="1" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/char_3"
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/char_6"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/char_1"
         android:src="@drawable/char_3"
         android:text="1" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/char_2"
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/char_3"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_config_label2"
         android:src="@drawable/char_2"
         android:text="1" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/user_name"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
         android:text="Name  :"
         android:textSize="26sp" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/user_name_textbox"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/user_name"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/user_name"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_name"
         android:ems="10" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/char_4"
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/char_1"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:src="@drawable/char_4"
         android:text="4" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/char_5"
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/char_4"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:src="@drawable/char_5"
         android:text="5" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/char_6"
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/game_types"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/char_5"
         android:src="@drawable/char_6"
         android:text="6" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/game_times"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/user_config_label2"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/game_types"
         android:entries="@array/game_times"
         android:textSize="22sp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/user_config_label1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/game_types"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/char_4"
         android:text="Game Types"
         android:textSize="22sp" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/game_types"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/user_name_textbox"
         android:layout_below="@+id/char_5"
         android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
         android:entries="@array/game_types"
         android:textSize="22sp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/user_config_label2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/user_config_back"
         android:layout_below="@+id/user_config_label1"
         android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
         android:text="Time Limit"
         android:textSize="22sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This open source form validation framework should suit your needs: https://github.com/inmite/android-validation-komensky

Primary features:

- Validate all views at once and show feedback to user. With one line of code.
- Live validation - check user input as he moves between views with immediate feedback.
- Extensible library - you can add your own validations or adapters for custom views.